# MS Project Viewer - Angular

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, angular, ms-project

Is there a way to display (embedded viewer) one MS Project File (MPP) in my Angular 9 application?

I need to show the gantt chart only. Just to view the content file, there is no need to edit.

If do you know a free solution is better!

Thanks